# Auto scalling of canvas dynamically using fabric.js for export on SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on simple editor that can add/edit text and image on a canvas. My default editor size is 480x317 but I want it to export on SVG using `.toSVG()` with a larger size 1075x709. The problem is when I tried to resize the canvas and export it. All object are not scale to my canvas size. It seem like it just resize the actual canvas but not the objects. Is there a function on fabric.js that can resize also the objects after the canvas resize? Here is the sample code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odegraciajr/L5WLL/12/)

Answer (score 1):

try to zoom canvas

```
    var originWidth = canvas.getWidth();

function zoom (width, height)
    {

        var scale = width / canvas.getWidth();
        height = scale * canvas.getHeight();

        canvas.setDimensions({
            "width": width,
            "height": height
        });

        canvas.calcOffset();
        var objects = canvas.getObjects();
        for (var i in objects) {
            var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
            var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
            var left = objects[i].left;
            var top = objects[i].top;

            objects[i].scaleX = scaleX * scale;
            objects[i].scaleY = scaleY * scale;
            objects[i].left = left * scale;
            objects[i].top = top * scale;

            objects[i].setCoords();
        }

        canvas.renderAll();

}

zoom (5000);
```

once you save revert back to normal with zoom

Answer (score 1):

fabric has built in method to do that.

```
var zoom = 4;
canvas.setZoom(zoom);
/* need to enlarge canvas otherwise the svg will be clipped */
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * zoom).setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * zoom);
var svg = canvas.toSVG();
/* need to set back canvas dimensions */
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() / zoom).setHeight(canvas.getHeight() / zoom);
```

an option to handle this automatically trough svg viewport is in the works.